# Showing that cosine is continous (not uniformly continuous)

Tags: continuity

I know that there exist many proofs that show $cos(x)$ is uniformly continous that rely on Lipschitz continuity and/or the mean value theorem. However, how can I show that $cos(x)$ is continuous in the first place? The mean value theorem requires that the function be differentiable (hence continuous) in the first place so I can't really use it without proving continuity.

Comment: Use the definition of continuity.

Comment: How do you define $\cos$? If you use the Taylor series, then continuity and differentiability follow since the radius of convergence in $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the unit circle.  Suppose $0< x < \pi/2$.  Then if you progress clockwise on the unit circle distance $x,$ 
you arrive at the point $(\cos(x), \sin(x))$.

The shortest distance to the origin from this point is $\sin(x)$.  That is shorter than the distance traveling along the unit circle, which is $x$.  We therefore know
$$\sin(x) < x, \qquad 0 < x <\pi/2.$$

You should be able to use the properties of sine and cosine to get to your general result.

Comment: Indeed, using this approach you have $\|(\cos x, \sin x) - (\cos y, \sin y)\| \le |x-y|$ directly.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\cos x-\cos y
&=-2\sin((x+y)/2)\sin((x-y)/2)\\
\text{so}\\
|\cos x-\cos y|
&=2|\sin((x+y)/2)\sin((x-y)/2)|\\
&\le 2|\sin((x-y)/2)|
\qquad\text{since } |\sin| \le 1\\
&\le |x-y|
\qquad\text{since }|\sin(z)| \le |z|\\
\end{array}
$